# For how many rows AJAX data loading in data tables makes sense

Tags: ajax, datatables

I am using a table with data tables plugin (https://datatables.net). I don't want to load data via AJAX because this causes trouble when using the download extension (will only download the loaded rows).

But I know that if my table is too big browser can get very slow when loading all rows at once.

So my question is: up to how many rows can I load at once in my HTML and when does it make sense to use ajax.

I know it depends on many factors...my table has around 7 columns. I don't need an exact number of course but are we talking about dozens, hundreds or thousands?

Thanks!

Comment: It's entirely subjective.  You'd have to determine a rough figure by testing your particular scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say about number of records, I believe up to 5000 should be acceptable. Depending on particular scenario.
There is FAQ about speed https://datatables.net/faqs/#speed

There is a way of viewing one set of data and saving another set.
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/customFile.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: // request to get a page of data,
        // ....
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'JSON',
                action: function ( e, dt, button, config ) {
                    var data = dt.buttons.exportData();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'your_server_data_file.json',
                        success: function(data) {
                            $.fn.dataTable.fileSave(
                                new Blob( [ JSON.stringify( data ) ] ),
                                'Export.json'
                            );
                        });
                }
            }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

And just in case https://datatables.net/manual/server-side